# Is there an easier way to apply the key to index without having to create a separate component for the pebble feed?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to display a pebble (message) in my Feed component on my App.
I am not entirely sure how to define index currently as everything is just wrapped in Text components for the time being.

Current code -

```
           {pebbles.map((pebble, index) => (
                <>
                    <Text>{currentUser.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{pebble.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{pebble.message}</Text>
                </>
            ))}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons}
                onPress={() => linkTo('/Send')}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Send New Pebble</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

    </>
) }
```

I'd like to simply just apply

```
key={index}
pebble={pebble}
title={pebble.title}
message={pebble.message}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const toSend = () => linkTo('/Send')
return (<>
 {pebbles.map((pebble, index) => (
                <View key={index}>
                    <Text>{currentUser.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{pebble.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{pebble.message}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons}
                onPress={toSend}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Send New Pebble</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
</>)
```